# Add JTextField in A new JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jtextfield

I have a `JFrame` with a `JButton` , this button open a new `JFrame` where there should be a text box ( `JTextField` ) that I will use for a search , the problem is that I don't know how to insert it . I came up with this :

N.B I'm a beginner, sorry in advance for the easy question :)

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class MainWindow {




// Seconda Finestra
public static void NuovaFinestra (JPanel panel) {

    panel.setLayout(null);



    JButton Ricerca = new JButton("Ricerca");
    Ricerca.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 50);
    panel.add(Ricerca);


    Ricerca.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             JFrame FinestradiRicerca = new JFrame("Finestra di Ricerca");
             FinestradiRicerca.setBounds(300, 300, 500, 500);

             FinestradiRicerca.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
             JPanel riquadroRicerca = new JPanel();
             FinestradiRicerca.add(riquadroRicerca);
             FinestradiRicerca.setVisible(true);
             JTextField ciao;
                ciao = new JTextField ();
                 }
    });

}




//Main  
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Finestra Principale
    JFrame finestra = new JFrame("Finestra principale");
    finestra.setSize(500, 500);
    finestra.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


//JPanel della finestra principale
    JPanel riquadro = new JPanel();
    finestra.add(riquadro);
    finestra.setVisible(true);

    NuovaFinestra(riquadro);

}





}
```

Comment: 1) You never add ciao to anything, that's why. 2) Don't use null layout, take a look at layout managers instead. 3) The use of multiple JFrames isn't really good practice 4) Please take a look at the Java code conventions (Also put `setVisible(boolean)` after adding the components)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You needed to add your new elements to `riquadroRicerca` BEFORE adding the Panel to `FinestradiRicerca`, I recommend you NOT to use `null` layout but a [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) or combinations of them. If you insist on keeping null layout then see below example. But for this kind of app I'd suggest a [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#card).

I also suggest not using multiple `JFrames` since they will open multiple windows on task bar which is user unfriendly. See: [Use of multiple JFrames, Good / Bad Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

As an aside note, follow [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). For example you called a `JFrame` as `FinestradiRicerca` instead rename it to: `finestradiRicerca` (1st letter of a *variable* in lowercase).

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MainWindow {
    // Seconda Finestra
    public static void NuovaFinestra (JPanel panel) {
        panel.setLayout(null);
        JButton Ricerca = new JButton("Ricerca");
        Ricerca.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 50);
        panel.add(Ricerca);
        Ricerca.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFrame FinestradiRicerca = new JFrame("Finestra di Ricerca");
                FinestradiRicerca.setBounds(300, 300, 500, 500);
                //If you don't want to close whole app when closing this windo change it to: JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE
                FinestradiRicerca.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JPanel riquadroRicerca = new JPanel();
                JTextField ciao;
                JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("Here goes your label text");
                ciao = new JTextField ();
                ciao.setColumns(20);
                riquadroRicerca.add(myLabel);
                riquadroRicerca.add(ciao);
                FinestradiRicerca.add(riquadroRicerca);
                FinestradiRicerca.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    //Main  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Finestra Principale
        JFrame finestra = new JFrame("Finestra principale");
        finestra.setSize(500, 500);
        finestra.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //JPanel della finestra principale
        JPanel riquadro = new JPanel();
        finestra.add(riquadro);
        finestra.setVisible(true);
        NuovaFinestra(riquadro);
    }
}
```

So, your code after a few modifications, to make `JLabel` and `JTextField` visible gives the following output:

[image]

However, please follow my above recomendations.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `JTextField` to your new JFrame like this. You also have to initialize your textfield. It is basically the same as you have done with the initial JFrame.

```
JTextField ciao = new JTextField();
FinestradiRicerca.add(ciao);
```